# In Spark Dataframe how to get duplicate records and distinct records in two dataframes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on a problem in which I am loading data from a hive table into spark dataframe and now I want all the unique accts in 1 dataframe and all duplicates in another. for example if I have acct id 1,1,2,3,4. I want to get 2,3,4 in one dataframe and 1,1 in another. How can I do this?

Comment: Logic: aggregate by id & count, join the counts back onto the original dataframe, `df_unique = df where id_count =1`, `df_dup = df where id_count >1`

Comment: Hi David.. I dint get it.. Is it that I have to get df.agg("acctid").count()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
val acctDF = List(("1", "Acc1"), ("1", "Acc1"), ("1", "Acc1"), ("2", "Acc2"), ("2", "Acc2"), ("3", "Acc3")).toDF("AcctId", "Details")
scala> acctDF.show()
+------+-------+
|AcctId|Details|
+------+-------+
|     1|   Acc1|
|     1|   Acc1|
|     1|   Acc1|
|     2|   Acc2|
|     2|   Acc2|
|     3|   Acc3|
+------+-------+
// Need to convert the DF to rdd to apply map and reduceByKey and again to DF to use it further more

val countsDF = acctDF.rdd.map(rec => (rec(0), 1)).reduceByKey(_+_).map(rec=> (rec._1.toString, rec._2)).toDF("AcctId", "AcctCount")

val accJoinedDF = acctDF.join(countsDF, acctDF("AcctId")===countsDF("AcctId"), "left_outer").select(acctDF("AcctId"), acctDF("Details"), countsDF("AcctCount"))

scala> accJoinedDF.show()
+------+-------+---------+   
|AcctId|Details|AcctCount|
+------+-------+---------+
|     1|   Acc1|        3|
|     1|   Acc1|        3|
|     1|   Acc1|        3|
|     2|   Acc2|        2|
|     2|   Acc2|        2|
|     3|   Acc3|        1|
+------+-------+---------+


val distAcctDF = accJoinedDF.filter($"AcctCount"===1)
scala> distAcctDF.show()
+------+-------+---------+   
|AcctId|Details|AcctCount|
+------+-------+---------+
|     3|   Acc3|        1|
+------+-------+---------+

val duplAcctDF = accJoinedDF.filter($"AcctCount">1)
scala> duplAcctDF.show()
+------+-------+---------+                 
|AcctId|Details|AcctCount|
+------+-------+---------+
|     1|   Acc1|        3|
|     1|   Acc1|        3|
|     1|   Acc1|        3|
|     2|   Acc2|        2|
|     2|   Acc2|        2|
+------+-------+---------+

(OR scala> duplAcctDF.distinct.show() )
```

Comment: Correct it me please if I'm wrong but you cann't operate with map or reduceByKey on Dataframes, you need to convert ir to rdd first and finally back to DF. Something like this: `val countsDF = acctDF.rdd.map....toDF()`

Answer (score 17):

Depending on the version of spark you have, you could use window functions in datasets/sql like below:

```
Dataset<Row> New = df.withColumn("Duplicate", count("*").over( Window.partitionBy("id") ) );

Dataset<Row> Dups = New.filter(col("Duplicate").gt(1));

Dataset<Row> Uniques = New.filter(col("Duplicate").equalTo(1));
```

the above is written in java. should be similar in scala and read this on how to do in python.
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

Answer (score 10):

```scala
df.groupBy($"field1",$"field2"...).count.filter($"count" > 1).show()
```